# Why SAP IQ load table option is faster than import wizard in the Interactive SQL?

Tags: database, csv, import, sap-iq

I did  CSV file import using SAP IQ LOAD TABLE SQL command which did it in less than a second, but with Interactive SQL import wizard tool it took almost 2+ hours. I am interested to know why it was so much faster. Table has more than 138'000 rows.

Why SAP IQ load table option is faster than import wizard in the Interactive SQL?

Answer (score 1):

The LOAD TABLE statement tells the database server to read the file directly. The import wizard tells the *client* to read the file and send the data to the server. Depending on the type of connection (shared memory, TCP/IP, encrypted or not, etc.) and the size of the file, the difference can be substantial.